# The grammar explanation of torch[cpuType]

Tags: lua, torch, resnet

I first see the usage in lua like `torch[cpuType]` in the file [dataloader.lua of fb.resnest.torch](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/master/dataloader.lua#L87):

```
batch = torch[cpuType](sz, nCrops, table.unpack(imageSize))
```

I didn't find any grammar explanation of it. How to understand it?

PS: `cpuType` is defined in the file, namely `self.cpuType`, I guess.

Update: From my test, `torch['FloatTensor']` is equivalent to `torch.FloatTensor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `torch[cpuType]` is the same as `torch.cpuType`.

The code (https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/master/dataloader.lua#L51-L57) seems to say that `cpuType` can take several different values, namely `DoubleTensor`, `FloatTensor` or `HalfTensor`. Consequently this notation creates a `torch.DoubleTensor` or `torch.FloatTensor` or `torch.HalfTensor`. It is a more compact notation for something like

```
if cpuType == 'torch.DoubleTensor' then
    batch = torch.DoubleTensor(sz, nCrops, table.unpack(imageSize))
elseif cpuType == 'torch.FloatTensor' then
    batch = torch.FloatTensor(sz, nCrops, table.unpack(imageSize))
elseif cpuType == 'torch.HalfTensor' then
    batch = torch.HalfTensor(sz, nCrops, table.unpack(imageSize))
```

Comment: Agreed. But the usage of `torch[...]` is strange, never met it before.

Comment: @Daniel same for me. I've seen a similar syntax used with `optim[optimMethod]()` (and the `optim` package) though

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge in pytorch, which is pretty much very similar to Lua Torch (I tried lua torch too), I would say it specifies where you want this tensor to be stored. Note that torch cannot perform an operation stored two different processing unit. There are methods to move data between cpu (net≈ß.cpu()) and gpu [net.cuda()].